# How to Handle Non-Standard Locale Codes in Django Templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, localization, internationalization

Can we use a non-standard locale code in Django ?

I want to use `es-lat` because in the film industry, the distinction is made between Spanish (`es` from Spain) and Latin American Spanish.

So far it seems to work with this settings

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "fr"
TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

LANGUAGES = [
    ("fr", _("French")),
    ("es", _("Spanish")),
    ("es-lat", _("Latin American Spanish")),
    ("en", _("English")),
]
```

But this piece of code in the templates treat `es-lat` as `es`.

```
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}
{% get_language_info_list for AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES as languages %}

{{ languages }}
# [{'bidi': False, 'code': 'fr', 'name': 'French', 'name_local': 'français', 'name_translated': 'Francés'}, {'bidi': False, 'code': 'es', 'name': 'Spanish', 'name_local': 'español', 'name_translated': 'Español'}, {'bidi': False, 'code': 'es', 'name': 'Spanish', 'name_local': 'español', 'name_translated': 'Español'}, {'bidi': False, 'code': 'en', 'name': 'English', 'name_local': 'English', 'name_translated': 'Inglés'}]
```

Is there a way to get my custom language code and name in the templates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Instead of iterating over the result of `get_language_info_list`, I iterate directly over `AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES`

```
{% get_current_language as CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}
{% get_available_languages as AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}

{% for CODE, NAME in AVAILABLE_LANGUAGES %}
  <a href=" {% if CODE == "fr" %}/{% else %}/{{ CODE }}/{% endif %}"
    class="dropdown-item {% if CODE == CURRENT_LANGUAGE %}active{% endif %}">
    {{ NAME }}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

This finds the custom locale as expected.